# How to use Cases to delete specific lists from a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

To simplify things, let's say that I have a list:

```
aList = {{1,2,3,4},{2,2,6,6},{6,9,8,7},{6,6,6,3}}
```

and I want to use `Cases` to get rid of the lists that have two or more 6's. So the output would be:

```
{{1,2,3,4},{6,9,8,7}}
```

I was only able to make this:

```
Cases[aList,x_/;Table[Count[aList[[i]],6]>=2,{i,1,Length[aList]}][[FromDigits[Flatten[Position[aList,x]]]]]!=True
```

but it seems... not simple, and it doesn't work with longer lists. Any suggestions?

Comment: `DeleteCases[aList, x_ /; Count[x, 6] > 2]` or alternatively `Cases[aList, x_ /; Count[x, 6] <= 2]` or alternatively `Select[aList, Count[#, 6] <= 2 &]`

Comment: Or, using _Pick_: `aList//Pick[#,UnitStep[Count[#, 6]&/@#-2],0]&`

Comment: also `DeleteCases[{___, 6, ___, 6, ___}]@aList` and `Cases[Except[{___, 6, ___, 6, ___}]]@aList`

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 2, 6, 6}, {6, 9, 8, 7}, {6, 6, 6, 3}};

DeleteCases[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[6, 6, __]}]
```

{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 9, 8, 7}}

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {{OrderlessPatternSequence[6, 6, __]}}]
```

{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 9, 8, 7}}

```
Extract[list, Position[Position[6] /@ list, {} | {{_}}]]
```

{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 9, 8, 7}}

Comment: Also: `DeleteCases[list, {___, OrderlessPatternSequence[6, 6], ___}]`

Answer (score 1):

```
aList = {{1,2,3,4},{2,2,6,6},{6,9,8,7},{6,6,6,3}}
Select[aList, Length[Cases[#, 6]] < 2 &]

{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 9, 8, 7}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2, 2, 6, 6}, {6, 9, 8, 7}, {6, 6, 6, 3}};
```

---

Using `Replace` and `Count`:

```
Replace[list, x_ /; ! Count[x, 6] < 2 :> Nothing, {1}]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 9, 8, 7}}*)
```

Or using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[list, {OrderlessPatternSequence[__, Repeated[6, {2, ∞}]]}]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 9, 8, 7}}*)
```

Or using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, x : {b__ /; Count[{b}, 6] < 2}, ___} :> x]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 9, 8, 7}}*)
```

Or using `DeleteCases` and `Count`:

```
DeleteCases[list, {b__ /; Count[{b}, 6] >= 2}]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {6, 9, 8, 7}}*)
```